How to remove two envoys from docker system to k8s given that the paths are repeated?
I used to have two envoys via docker that were located on the same virtual machine. In them I had the same paths, but also different clusters for different services were registered.
envoy 1:
static_resources:
  listeners:
    - address:
        socket_address:
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: 8888
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
                codec_type: AUTO
                upgrade_configs:
                  - upgrade_type: websocket
                stat_prefix: ingress_http
                access_log:
                  - name: envoy.access_loggers.stdout
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.stream.v3.StdoutAccessLog
                route_config:
                  name: local_route
                  virtual_hosts:
                    - name: backend
                      domains:
                        - "*"
                      routes:
                        - match:
                            prefix: "/some/path"
                          route:
                            prefix_rewrite: "/path"
                            cluster: my-service-from-first-docker

In docker it looked like this:
  first-envoy:
    image: $IMAGE
    ports:
      - '8888:8888'
      - '9900:8888'
    restart: unless-stopped
...

envoy 2:
static_resources:
  listeners:
    - address:
        socket_address:
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: 8888
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
                codec_type: AUTO
                upgrade_configs:
                  - upgrade_type: websocket
                stat_prefix: ingress_http
                access_log:
                  - name: envoy.access_loggers.stdout
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.stream.v3.StdoutAccessLog
                route_config:
                  name: local_route
                  virtual_hosts:
                    - name: backend
                      domains:
                        - "*"
                      routes:
                        - match:
                            prefix: "/some/path"
                          route:
                            prefix_rewrite: "/path"
                            cluster: my-service-from-second-docker

In docker it looked like this:
In docker it looked like this:
  second-envoy:
    image: $IMAGE
    ports:
      - '8585:8888'
      - '9100:8888'
    restart: unless-stopped
...

You can't connect to different host domain names now, you have to do everything on one foo.bar.com.
How do I do this with Ingress in mind?
As I understand it, it only works through 80 and 443 ports
I've tried attaching everything to nodePort and attaching them to them. It came out successfully, but it looks very wrong.
Unfortunately I can't change the paths themselves either. They are hardwired into my developers code

You're showing a compose file, but talking about ingresses and node ports. How are you deploying the compose file to kubernetes? And why not use a Ingress Controller like Contour or Ambassador?
